# Web.config httpCompression section is ignored

Tags: .net, iis, web-config, applicationhost

I am trying to add a mimeType in web.config -> httpCompression -> dynamicTypes.
What i found was that it had no effect and it seems that the section is being ignored.
For example:
Adding this element gives no error

```
<dynamicTypes>
    <addfail mimeType="someType" invalidAttribute="true" />
</dynamicTypes>
```

Or this

```
<dynamicTypes>
    qwerty
</dynamicTypes>
```

But when i change this for example:

```
<system.web>
    <customErrorsssssss mode="Off" />
</system.web>
```

I get an Internal server error.

What am i missing?